# Re-ordering search results changes results

Tags: civievent, drupal, search, participants, 5.13

Has anyone else seen this bug or reported it?

I ran a Participant Search with the search criteria set to the event name and event type (exhibition). The search returned 22 bookings. 
But if I reorder the list by clicking on any of the column headers the results change to include bookings from our differently named conference (different event name and type).

I'm using Drupal 7 and Civi 5.13.4.
I have replicated the bug on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/981 with a fix included in 5.14.0

Comment: Thank you Aidan